# How to detect seasonality without plotting in Python

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-analysis

I have 5 years of data for multiple variables (weekly data). My goal is to identify which ones have seasonality and which ones don't. I searched for a statistical test or something but couldn't find anything. How can you test for seasonality without plotting and at scale?

I need something returning TRUE and FALSE

Here is the data looks like:

[image: dataNumberOne]

This is the seasonality I need to identify:

[image: plotNumberTwo]

If any variable showing a seasonality trend like this, I want to tag it as seasonal.
Is there any test for this or which way is the best to detect it?

Comment: Please paste the actual data, not a picture of it.

Comment: Did you find answer to this question?